# Convert string to PAnsiChar in Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I'm converting my applications to Delphi 2009 and faced an intriguing issue with some calls that need to convert a string (wide) to AnsiString.

Here's an example to demonstrate the issue I'm having:

```
var
  s: PAnsiChar;

...

s := PAnsiChar(Application.ExeName);
```

With Delphi 2007 and previous versions, s := PChar(Application.ExeName) would return the application exe path.

with Delphi 2009, s := PAnsiChar(Application.ExeName) returns only 'E'.

My guess is that's because I'm converting a unicode string to an ansi string but how can I convert it so that a PAnsiChar gets the full string?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I have no Delphi 2009 here, so I can't check it. But maybe you have to try:

```
s := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(Application.ExeName));
```

As gabr already pointed, this is not a very good practice, and you will only use it if you are 100% sure. The string only contains characters that have a direct mapping to the ANSI range.

That's why you should get a warning because you are converting Unicode to ANSI.

Comment: You shouldn't because it is an explicit conversion.

And, yes, it should work.

Comment: I know, but the conversion to PAnsiChar is also a bit questionable.

Comment: It does work at the cost of the explicit conversion. Is there any other alternative? The conversion to PAnsiChar is explained on my reply below.

Comment: The problem is that you always have the chance of information loss. It is possibly better to change the PAnsiChar for a string.

Comment: In XE5 this problem caused me to have failed calls to dll including shellexecute. simply casting PAnsiChar(myStringVar) caused non detectable and non-reproducible errors and I was frustrated until the same thing happened with an external dll and I came to this solution. works fine now. Anybody with shell-execute problem should also check this out.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using type `String`, use `RawByteString`:

```
s: RawByteString;

s := LoadSomeRegularString(usually a string type);

PAnsiChar(s) <<< all fine.
```

Comment: No, don't do that. That is a total abuse of `RawByteString`. Instead of doing this, read the documentation for `RawByteString` and work out what it is really intended for.

Answer (score 1):

Gamecat explicit conversion works. I'm explaining the problem in more detail below so that perhaps someone can point to a better solution.

I'm using the following function to retrieve the application compilation date:

```
function LinkerTimeStamp(const FileName: string): TDateTime;
var
  LI: TLoadedImage;
begin
  {$IFDEF UNICODE}
  Win32Check(MapAndLoad(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(FileName)), nil, @LI, False, True));
  {$ELSE}
  Win32Check(MapAndLoad(PChar(FileName), nil, @LI, False, True));
  {$ENDIF}
  Result := LI.FileHeader.FileHeader.TimeDateStamp / SecsPerDay + UnixDateDelta;
  UnMapAndLoad(@LI);
end;
```

MapAndLoad requires a PAnsiChar for the ImageName Parameter so I need to convert the unicode string. Is there any other alternative as to explicitly convert to AnsiString first?

Comment: No, I don't think there is a Unicode version. CodeGear Imagehlp unit declares MapAndLoad as a LPSTR which maps to PAnsiChar. And no mention on msdn about an Unicode version.

Comment: You should probably add a comment what you changed for Unicode compatibility, and remove the IFDEF altogether - PAnsiChar and AnsiString are available at least in Delphi 4 already, and the typecasts do not hurt in Ansi programs.  The simpler the code the better IMHO.

Comment: This IFDEF is quite pointless. Simply write `PAnsiChar(AnsiString(FileName))` which works everywhere. Surely though a better solution is to find an alternative to `MapAndLoad` that isn't so lame as to require ANSI input.

Comment: The better solution, since you are doing this on the executing module, is as follows: `Result := PImageNtHeaders(HInstance + PImageDosHeader(HInstance)^._lfanew)^.FileHeader.TimeDateStamp / SecsPerDay + UnixDateDelta;`

Answer (score 0):

[WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms776420%5C(VS.85%5C).aspx) could help you.

Comment: WideCharToMultiByte is used internally in some casts of Delphi

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. The `PAnsiChar` only points to the first character. I wrote the following function to handle the old functionality.

```
// This function converts a string to a PAnsiChar
// If the output is not the same, an exception is raised
// Author: nogabel@hotmail.com

function StringToPAnsiChar(stringVar : string) : PAnsiChar;
Var
  AnsString : AnsiString;
  InternalError : Boolean;
begin
  InternalError := false;
  Result := '';
  try
    if stringVar <> '' Then
    begin
       AnsString := AnsiString(StringVar);
       Result := PAnsiChar(PAnsiString(AnsString));
    end;
  Except
    InternalError := true;
  end;
  if InternalError or (String(Result) <> stringVar) then
  begin
    Raise Exception.Create('Conversion from string to PAnsiChar failed!');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `PAnsiChar(AnsiString(stringVar))` is all you need.

Comment: Won't that have a problem with AnsString being a local variable and therefore Result pointing to that variable which will no longer be available after the function exits? In other words, an Access Violation in the waiting?

Answer (score -2):

I think You are a bit off.
Every Win32 API function has a unicode counterpart, if it is expecting a string.
Try **MapAndLoadW** instead of **MapAndLoad**...

Comment: There's no MapAndLoadW. It was the first thing I looked at. Not all Win32 APIs have unicode counterparts, most do but some like this one do not.