# Converting UnicodeString to PAnsiChar in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, pointers, delphi-xe, unicode-string, ansistring

In Delphi XE I am using the [BASS audio library](http://www.un4seen.com/), which contains this function:

```
function BASS_StreamCreateURL(url: PAnsiChar; offset: DWORD; flags: DWORD; 
    proc: DOWNLOADPROC; user: Pointer):HSTREAM; stdcall; external bassdll;
```

The 'url' parameter is of type PAnsiChar, so in my code I do a cast:

```
FStreamHandle := BASS_StreamCreateURL(PAnsiChar( url ) [...]
```

The compiler emits a warning on this line: "suspicious typecast of string to PAnsiChar". In trying to eliminate the warning, I [found that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283759/convert-string-to-pansichar-in-delphi-2009) the recommended way is to use a double cast:

```
FStreamHandle := BASS_StreamCreateURL(PAnsiChar( AnsiString( url )) [...]
```

This does eliminate the warning, but the BASS function now returns error code 2 ("cannot open file"), which tells me the URL string it receives is somehow broken. I cannot see what the bass DLL actually receives, but using a breakpoint in the debugger the string looks good:

```
var
  s : PAnsiChar;
begin
  s := PAnsiChar( AnsiString( url ));
```

At this point string s appears fine, but the BASS function fails when I pass it. My initial code: PAnsiChar( url ) works well with BASS, but emits a warning.

So what's the correct way of getting from UnicodeString to PAnsiChar without a warning?

Comment: I just used AnsiString
AnsiString: myURL;
myURL:='http://...'
BASS_StreamCreateURL(PAnsiChar( myURL ),0, [...]
and worked on Delphi XE2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am amazed that

```
BASS_StreamCreateURL(PAnsiChar( url ) [...]
```

works. If `url` is a unicode string, each character will occupy two bytes. If, for instance, the string is `test`, it will read

```
7400 6500 7300 7400 0000                t e s t #0                     (Unicode)
```

in memory. Notice that the string ends at the null character (`0000`) When you do

```
PAnsiChar(url)
```

you will tell the compiler that the memory at this address should be thought of as an `AnsiString`. But if you consider the above sequence of bytes, you will find only "t" in this case. Indeed, as an `AnsiString`, the sequence should be interpreted as

```
74 00 65 00 73 00 74 00 00 00           t #0 e #0 s #0 t #0 #0 #0      (Ansi)
```

which is the string "t", ending with the null character (`00`).

```
PAnsiChar(AnsiString(url))
```

on the other hand will first convert the unicode string to an ansi string, that is, you will obtain

```
74 65 73 74 00                           t e s t #0                    (Ansi)
```

which is the string "test" ending with the null character (`00`).

## Update

I am not psychic (yet), but maybe the Bass library actually does require a pointer to a `UnicodeString` as the first argument to this function? That would explain why the seemingly odd

```
PAnsiChar(url)
```

works. The library might say "Hey, just give me the pointer to the unicode string, and I'll do some manual processing with it" and the code above does just that (a pointer is just a pointer (that is, an unsigned 32 bit integer)...). But the compiler will complain, of course, because the library explicity told the compiler that it will require a `PAnsiChar`, and normally `PAnsiChar(SomeUnicodeString)` is bad. If this is the case, of course, then,

```
PAnsiChar(AnsiChar(url))
```

doesn't work. The library expects /the address of/ a unicode string, but gets /the address of/ an ansi string.

## Update 2

If my hypothesis in **Update 1** is correct, the declaration

```
function BASS_StreamCreateURL(url: PWideChar; offset: DWORD; flags: DWORD; 
    proc: DOWNLOADPROC; user: Pointer):HSTREAM; stdcall; external bassdll;
```

would make the skies blue again.

## Update 3

From the documentation:

> NOTE: Delphi 2009 users should use the BASS_UNICODE flag where possible

I bet that the problem will go away if you specify this flag when you call `BASS_StreamCreateURL`!

From the sample unit `Main.pas`:

```
Channel := BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE, PChar(OpenDialog.FileName), 0, 0,
    0 {$IFDEF UNICODE} or BASS_UNICODE {$ENDIF});
```

Comment: I agree entirely with your analysis. And yet, the "suspiciuos" typecast works, while the one that should be correct produces an error from BASS. Same behavior in Delphi XE and 2009. (One of the demos that come with BASS also uses the simple cast from string to PAnsiChar.)

Comment: Re your Update 3: the BASS_UNICODE flag is indeed present in my code. And you are probably right in your earlier hunch. Since the flag *is* specified, BASS expects a PWideChar, even though the declaration says otherwise. Thanks a lot, Andreas!

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippets works great in my experience. 
`{$IFDEF UNICODE}` or `BASS_UNICODE {$ENDIF}`